# Confusion about Numpy notation

Tags: numpy, matrix

If a is numpy array of shape (5,3) and b is of shape (2,4), what is the shape of a[b]?

In the above equation, what does a[b] really implies? Is it multiplication?

Comment: It's indexing, selecting items from `a` with indices provided by `b`.  Test it yourself.  I'd expect a (2,4,3) if elements of `b` are in 0-4 range.

Comment: Is `b` an array, or a tuple of length 2 of arrays of length 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not any kind of multiplication at all. This is an *advanced indexing*. Assuming the elements of `b` are valid indices into rows of `a`, then `a[b]` will be a 3D array with shape `(2,4,3)`. In your example, that means `b` should be an integer array with values between -5 and 4 inclusive, else indexing `a[b]` will raise `IndexError`. The result `a[b]` will be made up of the corresponding rows from `a`, stacked in depth.

This feature of numpy is documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

Comment: Boolean `b` won't work as index unless it's shape matches `a`s.